# Extracting special sublists from a list

Tags: filtering

**modified list**

From a numerical evaluation I get examplary result

```
    list = { {{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062,
      2.96321}}, {{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 
     4.8004, 1.27159}, {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{6.2694, 
     0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}, {{14.6342, 0.01, 4.9002, 
     0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859, 0.01, 
     4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555, 
     0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}} ,
  {{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}}
  }
```

`list` contains sublists of length 4. grouped to one or three elements.

I tried `Select[list,Length[#]==1&]` without success

My question:

- How can I extract list in a sublist, which only contains one sublist of four elements.
- How can I extract list in a sublist, which only contains three sublists of four elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To also answer the **revised question**:

Sublists of length 1

```
sel = Select[#, Length[#] == 1 &] & /@ list
```

{{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062,
2.96321}}, {{6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}}, {{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}}}

Sublists of length 1 with 4 elements (all of them have 4 elements)

```
Cases[sel, {Repeated[_, {4}]}, -1]
```

{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}, {5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062,
2.96321}, {6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}, {5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064,
2.96708}}

4 sublists with 4 elements don't exist:

```
Select[#, Length[#] == 4 &] & /@ list
```

{{}, {}}

But there are three sublists with 4 elements

```
sub = Select[#, Length[#] == 3 &] & /@ list
```

{{{{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 4.8004,
1.27159}, {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{14.6342, 0.01,
4.9002, 0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859,
0.01, 4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555,
0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}, {}}

```
Map[Length, sub, {3}]
```

{{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4}}, {}}

Comment: (+1)  Also (operator form):  `Select[Length[#] == 1 &]  /@ list`

Comment: Thanks, 1066, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

Sublists of length 1

```
sel = Select[list[[1]], Length[#] == 1 &]
```

{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062,
2.96321}}, {{6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}}

Sublists of length 1 with 4 elements (all of them have 4 elements)

```
 Cases[sel, {Repeated[_, {4}]}, {2}]
```

{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}, {5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062,
2.96321}, {6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}

4 sublists with 4 elements don't exist:

```
Map[Length, Select[list[[1]], Length[#] == 4 &], {2}]
```

{}

But there are 3 sublists, all of them with 4 elements:

```
Map[Length, Select[list[[1]], Length[#] == 3 &], {2}]
```

{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4}}

Here they are:

```
Select[list[[1]], Length[#] == 3 &]
```

{{{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 4.8004,
1.27159}, {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{14.6342, 0.01,
4.9002, 0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859,
0.01, 4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555,
0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My underlying problem is a bit more complicated, because `{list[[1]]}!=list `. I have to modify my question

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to handling additional braces is to use `Catenate` and then use `Position` and `Extract`:

```
list = {{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062, 2.96321}}, 
        {{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 4.8004, 1.27159}, 
        {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{6.2694,0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}, 
        {{14.6342, 0.01, 4.9002, 0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, 
        {15.0859, 0.01, 4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, 
        {15.6555, 0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}};

        Union@Extract[#, Position[#, m_ /; Length[m] == 3]] &@Catenate@list

        (*{{{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 4.8004, 1.27159}, 
         {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{14.6342, 0.01, 4.9002, 0.223376}, 
         {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859, 0.01, 4.9002, 2.68233}}, 
         {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555, 0.01, 5., 1.36177}, 
         {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you intentionally write double braces? If yes, you need to take care of this. E.g. you may write:

```
list = {{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062, 
      2.96321}}, {{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 
      4.8004, 1.27159}, {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{6.2694, 
      0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}, {{14.6342, 0.01, 4.9002, 
      0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859, 0.01, 
      4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555, 
      0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}};

Select[list[[1]], (Length[#] == 1) &]

{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062, 
   2.96321}}, {{6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}}
```

Further, you do not have sublists of length 4, but of length 3. To get these, you may write:

```
Select[list[[1]], (Length[#] == 3) &]

{{{14.4801, 0.01, 4.8004, 0.232071}, {15.1634, 0.01, 4.8004, 
   1.27159}, {14.7847, 0.01, 4.8004, 2.70053}}, {{14.6342, 0.01, 
   4.9002, 0.223376}, {15.4072, 0.01, 4.9002, 1.31633}, {15.0859, 
   0.01, 4.9002, 2.68233}}, {{14.7904, 0.01, 5., 0.215253}, {15.6555, 
   0.01, 5., 1.36177}, {15.3868, 0.01, 5., 2.66285}}}
```

Another possibility is to use Select as an operator like:

```
Select[Length[#] == 1 &] /@ list

{{{{5.65594, 0.01, 1.8064, 2.96708}}, {{5.96278, 0.01, 1.9062, 
    2.96321}}, {{6.2694, 0.01, 2.006, 2.9591}}}}
```

Comment: The double curly brakets came from `Table` evaluation. Probably my example is to simple, because my underlying problem has a more complicated structure with `{list[[1]]}!=list`